# How do I get the Null property of a column from SQL into C#

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I am using Web Api and I need to get the column information from a table in the database. I need to be able to hold in a variable if the column allows nulls or it is required/not null.

How can I do that in C#? Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible. Nearly every dbms has system/information/meta-tables that holds the information of the table definitions and stuff like that. It depends on the dbms you're using. For MSSQL you have to look for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`...

Comment: you need actual schema data?

What database?  Because your actual question could be answered by "a boolean variable" which I suspect is not what you really want to know.

Comment: Database is SQL. Yes I need to know before hand if a column allows null or not for validation.

Comment: What is with the downvote? Do people go around downvoting questions all day? Does that make them feel better?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because your question shows a severe lack of research. Almost like you didn't even try to google for the answer before posting your question.

Comment: The downvote is most likely because the question shows no attempt at research or that you even attempted a solution. Look into `sys.columns` to get your metadata.

Comment: @CodeMan03, It's your question so you have an emotional bond with it. But honnestly read this: "I am using Something, I need Something. How? Is it possible?" and tell me yu don't feel the urge to get some lighter fuild. It's vague, Unclear, the answer can be "1. By Coding. 2. Yes.", Tooboard: from sql to dataset you do understand there is at least 1 hundred way to get data.

Comment: And "Database is SQL" is not meaningful. Do you mean MS SQL Server? If so, add the appropriate tag. There's also MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQLite, etc. They are all "SQL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of MSSQL you can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` like this:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable' AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'yourColumn'
```

Do this at application start and cache the data for better performance...

[MSDN: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql)
[MSDN: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql)

Comment: Can an entity model be created from the information-schema?

Comment: @CodeMan03 I'm sorry, I don't know. Never tried that...